# Outbound calls using AWS Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I'm in charge of creating an implementation that honestly I don't know how to do it, this is the thing:

I need to do that when a client receives a hook notification from a services that they use, this notification activates and outbound call from AWS connect(only using a bot voice, not a real person calling) to notify the client faster than reading a notification, because the notifications are about serious things, so that's why they need a call, which is as I said, faster that reading a notification.

I've made some research, and seems that I need:

- use AWS polly to make my audio that is gonna be played in the call, I've created the audio and saved it in a AWS s3 bucket.
- I´ve created an AWS connect contact flow(idk exactly how to use AWS connect), which starts with a lambda function that is supposed to import the audio from s3, and then the next block of the flows has to make the call.
- I don't know how to make an outbound call from connect, specifically I don't know how to upload or indicate an specify number or list of numbers to call(I'm not from US)

Honestly I don't know how to connect all these things to make it work, do I have to use the AWS connect API or it can be made all from the lambda function?

so, if you have any idea of experience using AWS connect I'd appreciate it so much.